# Conjugate of exponential imaginary number

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

The conjugate of $e^{-iwt}$ is $e^{iwt}$.

Then, what would be the conjugate of $e^{iwt}$? Would it be $e^{-iwt}$?

Also, for $|e^{iwt}|^2$, what would the value look like?

Comment: Your first formula is correct only if $w t$ is real...

Comment: What are $\,w,t\,$? Real, complex...?

Comment: Also, "linear-algebra" is not a good tag for this question (try instead something like complex-variables).

Comment: **Given** the first, sure.

Comment: In general $\overline{e^{z}} = e^{\overline{z}}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Complex conjugation is an automorphism of order 2, meaning $\,\overline{\overline z}=z\,\,,\,\,\forall\,z\in\Bbb C\,$ , so if the conjugate of $\,e^{-iwt}\,$ is $\,e^{iwt}\,$ , then the conjugate of the latter is the former.

Also, writing the trigonometric version of $\,e^{ix}\,\,,\,x\in\Bbb R\,$ , you can check at once that $\,|e^{ix}|=1\,\,\,,\,\,\forall x\in\Bbb R\,$